# how do i ignore characters like '\n' in a string without removing them?

Tags: python, string, function

I am trying to edit to replace translate it into ROT13 form a string that could contain multiple occurrences of `\n` or `\t`.

e.g  `example_string = "\x0c\n\r\\;(ap8y+"`

is there a method where i could ignore these and treat them as regular string characters without removing them?

I've tried using the .strip() function, but this removes the \n completely, something I'm trying to avoid.

Expectation

`"input = "\x0c\n\r\\;(ap8y+"` `output = "\k0p\a\e\\;(nc8l+"`

Reality (using `input.strip()`

`"input = "\x0c\n\r\\;(ap8y+"` `input = "\;(ap8y+"`

Comment: Your expected output is exactly the same as the input, so... just do nothing?

Comment: When you say "ignore" I am not sure what you mean? Can you give an example of how you might want to ignore these characters without say just using the string "as is"?

Comment: Edit without removing is an interesting concept. Also, bearing in mind that strings are immutable you can't actually edit them anyway. You can create different versions perhaps with newline and tab ignored but you can't edit them *per se*. Also, your example of using strip() is flawed. Strip will removed leading and trailing whitespace but not embedded whitespace (or anything else for that matter)

Comment: updated the qustion to clarify my goal more clearly,

im trying to make a rot13 translator, but the \n, \t, and \r characters are getting in the way of translation

i apologize for the confussion

Comment: Hard to provide an answer without seeing the code that wants to ignore them, but I suggest using `str.maketrans` and `str.translate` to implement this. The call to `maketrans` will return a translation table that includes no-op translations like `\n -> \n`, but the argument(s) to `maketrans` only have to specify the actual changes.

Comment: You want to replace the `x` and `c` of `"\x0c"`? Are you sure?

Comment: Classic ROT13 only works for the letters A-Z and a-z. Characters not in those ranges are left as is. Therefore the ROT13 mapping of "\x0c\n\r\\;(ap8y+" is "\x0c\n\r\\;(nc8l+". In other words, only the a, p and y characters are substituted. Note: '\x0c' == '\f'

Answer (score 0):

Does this do wat you are looking for:
https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/2y6cu/

```
def rot13(s):
    result = []
    for char in s:
        if 'a' <= char <= 'z':
            result.append(chr(((ord(char) - ord('a') + 13) % 26) + ord('a')))
        elif 'A' <= char <= 'Z':
            result.append(chr(((ord(char) - ord('A') + 13) % 26) + ord('A')))
        else:
            result.append(char)
    return ''.join(result)

example_string = "\x0c\n\r\\;(ap8y+"
rot13_string = rot13(example_string)

print(f"Input: {example_string!r}")
print(f"Output: {rot13_string!r}")
```